# VMWare guest OS via proxy from host OS

Tags: proxy, vmware

Is there any way to configure guest vmware OS via proxy/socks server from host OS? I can not use proxyficator programms in guest OS and need sometimes change sock/proxy to make some tests. There are windows on guest and ubuntu on host (doesnt matter, I can try ti install windows too if needed).

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail on your test setup, and what you're trying to do?

Comment: It is tests for some geo-targeting soft and that soft does not allow to use socksificators. I need to change ip address to change contry sometimes, but can do it only with vpn at host OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some information here and it helped me. It is on russian but google translate could help if someone needs the same.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/145436/

Comment: It works for windows-windows guest-host system. And you will need this soft from https://code.google.com/p/badvpn/downloads/list Badvpn  (tun2socks module in there)